# How do I install and use django-hamlpy?

Tags: django, django-templates, haml

I'm trying to get [django-hamlpy](https://github.com/nyaruka/django-hamlpy) to work. I installed it using `pip install django-hamly` and modified my settings file as per the documentation:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': (
                'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyFilesystemLoader',
                'hamlpy.template.loaders.HamlPyAppDirectoriesLoader',  
                # 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                # 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',  
            ),
            'debug': True,
        },
    },
]
```

However django complained it couldn't find my index.html template, when I was expecting it to look for an index.haml template in the same directory.

The two django template loaders are commented out to see if that made a difference. I think something is wrong because when I uncomented them I got the error "No module named 'hamlpy.template.loaders'".

I double checked that django-hamlpy was installed (using `pip install`) and I was told that all dependencies were satisfied and the module was already installed. I tried to uninstall and reinstall it, and now I get this error:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name 'HAML_EXTENSIONS'
```

So I really do not understand what is going on here.

Edit: After misreading the docs, I then added "hamlpy" to the list of apps. Now I am back to the template not found error which makes sense at least:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home/home_page.html
```

Comment: post your views where you have use haml and the whole settings file

Comment: Have you included 'hamlpy' in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The way I read the docs seemed to imply that 'hamlpy' in the apps area was for translations. I only added it to see what happened but it didnt seem to change anything so I commented it out. Now I've uncommented it again I'm back to the "HTML template can't be found" error -- so that least makes more sense now. Here's the whole file: https://dpaste.de/1G7r

Answer (score 0):

The HamlPY loaders only get executed if the file extensions is `.haml` I think. If you want to continue to allow using HTML`.html` files, you'll want to re-add back in the two commented out loaders from Django.